# Joining one more table to a SQL query that's just too complex for me

Tags: php, sql, left-join, oscommerce

I'm not all that well-versed in MySQL querying, and I usually only do very simple JOINs. I am working with an installation of osCommerce, and I want the category page to include products from all subcategories as well.

```
select
    p.products_image,
    pd.products_name,
    pd.products_description,
    p.products_id,
    p.manufacturers_id,
    p.products_price,
    p.products_tax_class_id,
    IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price,
    IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price
from
    products_description pd,
    products p
left join
    manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
left join
    specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id,
    products_to_categories p2c
where
    p.products_status = '1' and
    p.products_id = p2c.products_id and
    pd.products_id = p2c.products_id and
    pd.language_id = '1' and
    (p2c.categories_id = '24' or ###.parent_id = '24')
order by pd.products_name asc
```

Basically, I need to join the categories table to this query as well, pulling the row from the categories table where categories_id = p2c.categories_id. Then, I can reference the parent_id column from the selected row from the categories table (I would replace the "###" above with something like "cat").

However, I'm getting confused with all the left joins as to where I should insert another JOIN clause.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: . . If you formatted your queries, you might find them much easier to modify and maintain.

Comment: I do. osCommerce loves to throw them on really ridiculously long lines.

Comment: There. I reformatted the sample query in my question.

Comment: Just slap your next JOIN after the existing ones. Also, do yourself a favor and kill off the deprecated join syntax.

Comment: you're mixing two different join syntax styles. Pick one or the other, don't mix them. once you've got a consistent style, your question basically solves itself.

Comment: Again, being that I didn't write the original query and I'm not too familiar with joining, I am not sure where to go with this. Could you offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the tables to test against, but should be something as simple as;

```sql
SELECT
    p.products_image,
    ...
FROM products_description pd
JOIN products p
  ON pd.products_id = p.products_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m 
  ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
LEFT JOIN specials s 
  ON p.products_id = s.products_id
JOIN products_to_categories p2c
  ON p2c.products_id = p.products_id
JOIN categories c
  ON c.categories_id = p2c.categories_id
WHERE
    p.products_status = '1' and
    pd.language_id = '1' and
    (p2c.categories_id = '24' or c.parent_id = '24')
ORDER BY by pd.products_name ASC
```

Comment: I ended up just sticking JOIN categories c ON c.categories_id = p2c.categories_id just before the WHERE clause and leaving the rest of the query as it was, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!